# ERROR Error: The location argument should not be used if you pass an object to set(). when get user location using geofire ionic 5

Tags: angular, firebase-realtime-database, geofire, ionic5

I was trying to implement nearby users in my ionic 5 app but I got an error when storing user's location, this is the code:

```
// login and store uid in local storage
  uid = localStorage.getItem("uid");

  lat: number;
  lng: number;

  // GeoFire reference
  geoFire: any;

  // show spinner if data is loading
  isLoaded: boolean = false;

  // to store find nearby users
  usersAround: Array<any> = [];



  constructor(private toast: ToastController,
    private afAuth: AngularFireAuth,
  ) {
    const geofire = require('geofire');

    // database reference to store locations
    let dbRef = firebase.database().ref("locations");
    this.geoFire = new geofire.GeoFire(dbRef);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getUserLocation();
  }

  getUserLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position => {
        this.lat = position.coords.latitude;
        this.lng = position.coords.longitude;

        // set current user location
        this.geoFire.set(this.uid, [this.lat, this.lng]).then(() => {
          this.getUsersAround();
        }).catch((err)=>{
          console.log(err);
        });
      });
    }
  }

  getUsersAround(){
    this.geoFire.query({
      center: [this.lat, this.lng], //current user location
      radius: 1.609 //in kilometers
    }).on("key_entered", (key, location, distance)=>{
      // get users info using key
      firebase.database().ref("users/"+key).once("value", snap=>{
        // hide spinner
        this.isLoaded = true;
        // push user data
        this.usersAround.push({...snap.val(), location: location, distance: distance});
      });
    });
  }

  convert(distance){
    // distance is about 1.694843322102
    // we convert it to 1.6 km

    // if distance is less than one
    // return value in meters
    if(distance<=1){
      return Number(distance * 1000).toFixed(2) + " m away"; 
    }
    // else return value in kilometers
    else {
      return Number(distance).toFixed(2) + " Km away";
    }
    
  }
}
```

and this is the error:

> core.js:6260 ERROR Error: The location argument should not be used if you pass an object to set().

I searched a lot for a solution but I didn't find, can anyone please help me?

this is package.json:

```
{
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@agm/core": "^1.1.0",
    "@angular/common": "~9.1.6",
    "@angular/core": "~9.1.6",
    "@angular/fire": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~9.1.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~9.1.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~9.1.6",
    "@angular/router": "~9.1.6",
    "@ionic-native/call-number": "^5.26.0",
    "@ionic-native/camera": "^5.26.0",
    "@ionic-native/core": "^5.0.7",
    "@ionic-native/geolocation": "^5.26.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic/angular": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic/storage": "^2.2.0",
    "call-number": "^1.0.1",
    "cordova-android": "^8.1.0",
    "cordova-ios": "^5.1.1",
    "cordova-plugin-camera": "^4.1.0",
    "cordova-plugin-geolocation": "^4.0.2",
    "cordova-sqlite-storage": "^5.0.0",
    "firebase": "^7.17.1",
    "geofire": "^5.0.1",
    "ionic4-rating": "^1.0.9",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.1",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.901.5",
    "@angular/cli": "~9.1.5",
    "@angular/compiler": "~9.1.6",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~9.1.6",
    "@angular/language-service": "~9.1.6",
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit": "^2.1.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^12.12.48",
    "codelyzer": "^5.1.2",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "^2.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^4.2.1",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^5.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.4.2",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.3",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~5.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~3.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.3",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~3.8.3"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project",
  "cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
      "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
      "cordova-plugin-device": {},
      "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": {
        "ANDROID_SUPPORT_ANNOTATIONS_VERSION": "27.+"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": {},
      "cordova-sqlite-storage": {},
      "cordova-plugin-camera": {
        "ANDROID_SUPPORT_V4_VERSION": "27.+"
      },
      "mx.ferreyra.callnumber": {},
      "cordova-plugin-geolocation": {}
    },
    "platforms": [
      "ios",
      "android"
    ]
  }
}
```

ionic version:
6.4.0

npm version:
5.3.0

Comment: `this.geoFire.set(this.uid, [this.lat, this.lng])` can you check what the value of `this.uid` here is? Seems to be expecting a string and receiving object

Comment: @SurajRao it gives me null

Comment: then that is your issue. It needs to be a string value. You need to check why its null

Comment: Thanks a lot @SurajRao I will check it

Comment: I got this error now: ERROR Error: keyOrLocations must be a string or a mapping of key - location pairs. even when I got the right uid.

Comment: that seems to be related to your second array parameter... is the value correct?

Comment: It gives me the correct lat, lng but shows that error

Comment: sorry not sure what is wrong without knowing values you are passing. Check https://github.com/firebase/geofire-js/blob/15238ae198dfad42d4329e7646d2710c335030fc/docs/reference.md#geofiresetkeyorlocations-location

Comment: @SurajRao I will check the values it gets and will respond again, Thanks a lot.

Comment: @SurajRao I got these values 17.0459136,54.060646399999996